# Content Security Policy ignored by Latest Chrome Update

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, content-security-policy

My CSP policy is being ignored by the latest version of Chrome. I decided today to recreate the policy to try debug why, but as you can see from the error below, Chrome is advising me to add a hash that is already in the CSP (see **sha256-idz8mDU5fJ8lJuEwY6hbkXVde/nqBBjQE/u5rxw1HUk=**):

`Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://pro.fontawesome.com/ 'sha256-LpfmXS+4ZtL2uPRZgkoR29Ghbxcfime/CsD/4w5VujE=' 'sha256-F+21FF3QOEHS5CNuMQEs3Q+LB0uULZF9DODEYnH/mMQ=' 'sha256-5uIP+HBVRu0WW8ep6d6+YVfhgkl0AcIabZrBS5JJAzs=' 'sha256-nK6A3vwzvwoN92MnHZrWtylYkYmW1jCQgTqWKQJNBMI=' 'sha256-idz8mDU5fJ8lJuEwY6hbkXVde/nqBBjQE/u5rxw1HUk='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-idz8mDU5fJ8lJuEwY6hbkXVde/nqBBjQE/u5rxw1HUk='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

This is working correctly in Firefox and Safari, so I'm thinking that there is something in my policy that is causing Chrome to stop reading values?

The content of my .htaccess file is:

`Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; connect-src 'self'; font-src 'self' https://pro.fontawesome.com/; frame-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' https://pro.fontawesome.com/ 'sha256-LpfmXS+4ZtL2uPRZgkoR29Ghbxcfime/CsD/4w5VujE=' 'sha256-F+21FF3QOEHS5CNuMQEs3Q+LB0uULZF9DODEYnH/mMQ=' 'sha256-5uIP+HBVRu0WW8ep6d6+YVfhgkl0AcIabZrBS5JJAzs=' 'sha256-nK6A3vwzvwoN92MnHZrWtylYkYmW1jCQgTqWKQJNBMI=' 'sha256-idz8mDU5fJ8lJuEwY6hbkXVde/nqBBjQE/u5rxw1HUk=';"`

Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Or perhaps incorrectly reading the encoding of the file and thus the hash?

Answer (score 3):

I think this resource answers your question:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=546106

> The styles being blocked in the examples are styles in a style
>   attribute, Chrome only applies styles in style attributes when
>   'unsafe-inline' is set in 'style-src'. Safari behaves similarly but
>   Firefox does apply the styles if they match a hash in 'style-src'.
>
> The CSP specification defines the hash and nonce exceptions only for
>   the  and  elements, not for the style and script
>   attributes so Chrome's behaviour seems to follow the spec. But the
>   error message generated in the console is incorrect (and confusing).

By the looks of it Chrome is following the CSP specification. I was facing the same issue with inline styles and seeing the same response as you, matching sha256 hashes! My solution has been to remove my inline styles and add them into my CSS to avoid inline styles completely.

Answer (score 0):

While the console logged:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'
>   'sha256-tLBf5MoZ1LfLjLmXgREJmfznfoX6mUwoWQJnC30N6JI='. Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-tLBf5MoZ1LfLjLmXgREJmfznfoX6mUwoWQJnC30N6JI='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

The solution would be to add `'unsafe-hashes'`, like so: `style-src 'self' 'unsafe-hashes' 'sha256-tLBf5MoZ1LfLjLmXgREJmfznfoX6mUwoWQJnC30N6JI='`.

See the `'unsafe-hashes'` directive: https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#unsafe-hashes-usage